# L-2 integration and its properties

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Question: If $\lim_{n\to\infty}||{f_n-f}||=0$ then  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_I f_n\cdot g=\int_I f\cdot g$ for all $g\in L^2(I)$.

I believe that this implies that $f_n\to f$, but how does this fact then apply then to integration?

Comment: If your double-bars mean $L^2$-norm, and if your $f_n\to f$ means in the $L^2$ metric, then _of_course_ the latter is equivalent to the former. The assertion about the limit of integrals is, as @JackyChong observes, the Cauchy-Schwartz-Bunyakowsky inequality. That assertion does not really "imply" that $f_n\to f$ in an $L^2$ sense, but is a consequence of it.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: Observe you have
\begin{align}
\int_I (f_n-f)\cdot g \leq \|f_n-f\|_2 \|g\|_2.
\end{align}

Comment: Of course, more carefully, the absolute value of the LHS... and that this is by Cauchy-Schwartz-Bunyakowsky...